# Creating simple popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used the following codes to create a popup window. I want to create a popup window with a box  on the right side of my screen (bottom and on the corner). I could not do it. Could you please help me to do it . If there is no contact, I want people to close the window by clicking  on the X icon. Very much appreciated for your help

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script>
 $(function() {
  $(".dil").click(function () {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      position: { my: "right bottom", at: "right bottom", of: window }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
  </script>
.pop {display: none;}
  </head>
<body>
link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">

<button class="btn dil">Open</button>

<div class="messagepop pop" id="dialog">
  <form method="post" id="new_message" action="/messages">
    <p><label for="email">Your email or name</label><input type="text" size="30" name="email" id="email" /></p>
    <p><label for="body">Message</label><textarea rows="6" name="body" id="body" cols="35"></textarea></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Send Message" name="commit" id="message_submit"/> or <a class="close" href="/">Cancel</a></p>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: $( "#dialog" )... there is no such element with id dialog

Comment: Did you see my answer, @User20100?

Comment: Did my answer work for you? **You can reply to comments!**

Comment: Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a few simple basic changes, if you had read the docs correctly:

1. You should give the appropriate ID to the `.messagepop` as `#dialog`.
2. You should attach the `.dialog()` to a click event and not on load event.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".dil").click(function () {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      position: { my: "right bottom", at: "right bottom", of: window }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.pop {display: none;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">

<button class="btn dil">Open</button>

<div class="messagepop pop" id="dialog">
  <form method="post" id="new_message" action="/messages">
    <p><label for="email">Your email or name</label><input type="text" size="30" name="email" id="email" /></p>
    <p><label for="body">Message</label><textarea rows="6" name="body" id="body" cols="35"></textarea></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Send Message" name="commit" id="message_submit"/> or <a class="close" href="/">Cancel</a></p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank  you Praveen-  two things: it is appeared on  the middle of the screen. I want to see it on the corner at the bottom of my screen ( right side). The other thing is  there is no "contact us" on the bar. Would you advise me.

Comment: For making it on the bottom right of the screen, use: `position: { my: "right bottom", at: "right bottom", of: window }`. See the updated answer. What no contact us?

Comment: Sorry, still It comes up at the middle of the screen. I meant, I want to see "Contact us" at the top of the bar. Thanks

Comment: @User20100 Er... That's `bottom right` for me. What do you mean by center? http://i.imgur.com/lZZTuRC.png?1

Comment: When I open the page, it comes up at the middle of the screen. I need to drag it to the bottom right

Comment: Nopes, I get it in the bottom right only. Do one thing. Run the snippet and click on the full page and tell if it still comes in the middle.

Comment: Do you still have an issue?

Comment: Ah... Yes I guess. Try it on jsBin and share it with me.

Comment: I have  edited  the codes according your advice ( see above). Please can you check it and see what is the issue. Very much appreciated for your help

Comment: Have you had chance to look at it- Thanks

Comment: Praveen Kumar @ Have you find the solution. I wonder if other people can help

Comment: @User20100 Nothing yet buddy. Sorry.

Comment: Do you know someone to help us.

Comment: Would you remove your codes as people think you have solved it Please remove your codes

Answer (score 1):

You can check with the below link.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eARdt/209/)

```
    // Basic Feedback Tab from Lesson 2

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#box_form').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 375,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        buttons: [
            {
            text: "Cancel",
            click: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }},
        {
            text: "Submit",
            click: function() {
                $('#zFormer').submit();
            }}
        ]
    });
    $('#clicky').button().click(function(e){
        $('#box_form').dialog('open');
    });
});
```

Comment: This is not an answer that solves the OP's problem; that's the reason I downvoted, but I have removed it.

Comment: @ Steevan can you help please?